# Android one PNG screen image with EditTexts located on screen

Tags: android, background, png, android-edittext

I have a full screen png image with all descriptive text for each EditText. I want to place the six EditText input areas at the correct positions on the screen.

I understand the different layout folder names for different screen sizes, densities and orientations. So I would have different layout XML files for each.

My problem is how to place the EditTexts at the correct location, and have them scale what would be small amounts with the small variations of sizes as the full screen png image will scale.

I believe that I should not specify locations, even with density independent pixel (dp |dip), as they may not work in future versions.

I cannot find anything on searching for this problem. What I can think of is a Relative Layout with blank or transparent dummy TextViews pushing the EditTexts to the correct positions.

My reasons for doing it this way with one png image for all the non-EditText parts of the screen are (I think)
- Can get a nicer screen image
- Is more efficient to place one png ImageView on the screen
- Is how it was done in another mobile environment

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I'd remove the text parts from the background image and use a RelativeLayout. That would give you the best result in all cases (not to mention easiest for you).

Comment: Hi Jave, Do you mean have all the TextViews as well as the EditTexts located with the RelativeLayout? The background image would not have any text, although maybe have something that does not need to align with the EditTexts?

Comment: Exactly :) It would give you the best result and flexibility considering all the different screen sizes and resolutions available for Android phones and tablets.

Comment: Thanks Jave. Is there a way to mark this question as answered?

Comment: Added an answer based on my comments that you can accept :)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you remove any text parts and other that needs to be aligned from the background image, then create a `RelativeLayout` where you can add these as real `TextViews`/`EditText`s.
This will give you the best result and flexibility considering all the different screen sizes and resolutions available for Android phones and tablets.